# How to control an LED strip with RaspberryPi/ESP32 using N-channel MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, led, raspberry-pi, led-strip, gate-driving

I am trying to control my LED-strip with N-channel MOSFETs. The problem is it won't turn off after removing the current from the hate. More details below.

I bought these [MOSFETs,](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B072MD5839/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and am currently using the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with 4GB of RAM.

I wired everything as shown below according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96uqxLQ_VFo&list=PL-xcHmoN4XSEhmKzXdra1Z5BuMtCddDaq&index=2&ab_channel=BasementMaker):

[image: According to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96uqxLQ_VFo&list=PL-xcHmoN4XSEhmKzXdra1Z5BuMtCddDaq&index=2&ab_channel=BasementMaker]

For testing purposes, I used the 5V pin and only one MOSFET and tried it with only one LED.

The LED was off than I wired the 5V to the gate and the LED turned on.

The problem was that disconnecting this wire again didn't turn off the light. When I tried it with the same MOSFET again the light would be turned on from the beginning without anything connected to the gate.

Putting a resistor in-between didn't work either.

> I'm trying to do the same thing but using the ESP32.

I hope that wasn't too confusing.

Comment: Product description says BUZ11, but "Manufacturer reference:" is IRLZ44N. What is the _actual_ part number of these FETs?

Comment: One of the FETs does not have its gate connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a pull-down resistors in parallel from the gate of each MOSFET to a ground. Around 10K ohms will be fine for your application.

Comment: For anyone searching how to add resistor from gate to ground: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd6NzCY3NgI

Answer (score 0):

Mosfets have voltage driven high impedance input that have some capacitance. If you charge up the FET gate to 5V, disconnecting a wire won't turn off the FET, as the accumulated charge can't discharge by itself. Except very slowly due to leakage.

Now if it were a BJT, it would stop conducting as it has a current driven base input.